# Mapnik PointSymbolizer - dynamic svg path from column

Tags: mapnik

I want to visualize a shapefile with points, where each point should be rendered with a different symbol. The paths to symbols are provided in a column in the shapefile.

This is my current `stylesheet.xml`:

```xml
<Layer name="genai" srs="+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs">
    <StyleName>cluster-img</StyleName>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer allow-overlap="true" ignore-placement="true" opacity="1.0">
            <Parameter name="file">[image_path]</Parameter>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
</Layer>
```

However, this seems not to work, since I do not know where to put the file name for the shapefile.

The long way is to use something like this:

```xml
  <Style name="cluster-img">
      <Rule>
          <Filter>[image_path] = 'test_image_cluster0.png'</Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer
            file="test_image_cluster0.png" 
            allow-overlap="true" 
            ignore-placement="true" 
            opacity="1.0" 
            transform="scale(0.3,0.3)"/>
      </Rule>
      <Rule>
          <Filter>[image_path] = 'test_image_cluster1.png'</Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer 
            file="test_image_cluster1.png" 
            allow-overlap="true" 
            ignore-placement="true" 
            opacity="1.0" 
            transform="scale(0.3,0.3)"/>
      </Rule>
  </Style>
...
    <Layer name="genai" srs="+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs">
        <StyleName>cluster-img</StyleName>
        <Datasource>
          <Parameter name="encoding">UTF-8</Parameter>
          <Parameter name="type">shape</Parameter>
          <Parameter name="file">shapefiles_gg/gen_img.shp</Parameter>
        </Datasource>
    </Layer>
```

But I have over 100 different images, which will generate a very long stylesheet with mostly repetition. Is there any better solution? I looked into GroupSymbolizer, but this also does not seem to help here.